# Having trouble configuring Karma (Dart) to run to run guinness.dart tests in WebStorm

Tags: dart, karma-runner

I am trying to run guinness tests in WebStorm but it Karma does not seem to be recognising the guinness tests.

The following using unittest.dart works (gives me a pass and fail)

```dart
void main(){
    test('trivial', () {
        expect(1, equals(1));
    });

    test('trivial fail', () {
        expect(1, equals(2));
    });
}
```

When I switch to using guinness in the same file:

```dart
void main(){
  describe('stuff happens', (){

    it('works sometimes', (){
      expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('fails others', (){
      expect(1).toEqual(2);
    });

  });
}
```

Karma returns a result of NO TESTS.

Here is my karma.config.js

```dart
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '.',
        frameworks: ['dart-unittest'],

        files: [
            'test/*.dart',
            {pattern: '**/*.dart', watched: true, included: false, served: true},
            'packages/browser/dart.js',
            'packages/browser/interop.js'
        ],

        exclude: [
        ],

        autoWatch: true,
        captureTimeout: 20000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 300000,

        plugins: [
            'karma-dart'
        ],

        karmaDartImports: {
            guinness: 'package:guinness/guinness_html.dart'
        },

        browsers: ['Dartium']
    });
};
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Thanks
John

Comment: Have you tried to start the server with a config file stripped of the 'browsers' line? The Karma server hasn't included Dartium as an available browser.

Comment: Just tried - same result works fine with plain old unit test results in NO TESTS with guinness

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following import statement in the dart test file solved it for me:

```
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart' hide expect;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the linked tutorial. Maybe you're just missing the 'karma-chrome-launcher' in the plugins of your karma config file.

[Karma Dart Step by Step Setup](http://victorsavkin.com/post/88371594071/setting-up-karma-for-a-dart-project-step-by-step)